# gcloud datastore query, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: coffeescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

[image]

```
# initiating Datastore client
datastore = Datastore()

# initiating datastore Key
keyString = datastore.key {
    namespace: 'p-arachnid-test-ns'
    path: ['usertable', 234567]
  }

# Check Login Credentials
checkLoginCredentials = (requestedEmail, requestedPassword) ->  
  query = datastore.createQuery('test-task')
    .filter('__key__', '=', keyString)
    .filter('email', '=', requestedEmail)

  datastore.runQuery query, (err, tasks) ->
    if !err
      console.log "query success"
      console.log tasks
      return true
    else
      console.log err
      return false
```

**Error:**

> code: 400, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} }, message:
>   '**key** filter namespace is p-arachnid-test-ns but query namespace is
>   '

Answer (score 0):

As described in the error message, you have a mismatch between the namespace you are executing the query in, and the namespace of the key you are filtering by.

You can fix this by adding the namespace to the query creation step, so change:

```
query = datastore.createQuery('test-task')
```

to include the optional namespace parameter:

```
query = datastore.createQuery('p-arachnid-test-ns', 'test-task')
```

Comment: Hi Dan, you seem to be doing lots of tag edits which cause churn in the recent active GAE questions list which *might* be avoidable. I'd suggest asking a question on SO meta specifying exactly what tag management action(s) you're trying to do, there may be better ways to achieve it. See, for example, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work

Comment: Hi Dan! We've tried that path with no success. 19 Upvotes and no action yet: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285879/merge-request-for-google-cloud-datastore-gae-datastore-google-datastore, so as I'm reviewing/answering questions, I'm correcting tags. Would love to get traction on the linked Meta question.